# Intel VTune CPU OpenCL Command Queue

Tags: opencl, intel-vtune

I can view the Intel HD Graphics Command Queue with VTune, but I cannot the CPU Command Queue. Why? It is the expected behavior, to only capture GPU "events" but not those from the CPU that are independent of the GPU?

The same OpenCL program (a simple vector addition) running in the GPU shows the events (NDRange, etc) but in the CPU not (you only see clWrite,Read Buffer and clBuildProgram). Also, you cannot see any info in the region where CPU is working with OpenCL (clWaitForEvents).

CPU:

[image: CPU Command Queue]

GPU:

[image: GPU Command Queue]

Comment: Your type of analysis is GPU hotspots. May be that's the reason - VTune is just tracking GPU performance counters?

Comment: So, the question is, how can I get the same for the CPU? It is weird that they only show the GPU Command Queue and its events, not the CPU. Everybody needs a CPU to run a program (OpenCL supported), and just some computers have a GPU (OpenCL-capable GPU).

Alternatively, how would you get the CPU Command Queue info (OpenCL)?